# How can I change the src of img tag dynamically through re-rendering/useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a image uploader (Cloudinary) and when select a image locally, I want to change the  tag upon select. Right now, it is currently working but it has to refresh (I want it to re-render without refresh). Here is the code block for the image

```
              <div className="app-header">
                {/* Use the logoValue as the src attribute */}
                <img className="app-header-personal-logo" src={logoValue} alt="Logo" />
              </div>
```

I tried create a hook for the update of the image source.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getBusinessLogoImageUrl } from '../helpers/cloudinary'

const useCloudinaryStorageId = () => {
  const [cloudinaryStorageId, setCloudinaryStorageId] = useState<string | undefined>('');
  const [logoValue, setLogoValue] = useState<string | undefined>()



  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cloud: ", cloudinaryStorageId)
    if(cloudinaryStorageId) {
      const newLogoValue = getBusinessLogoImageUrl(cloudinaryStorageId);
      setLogoValue(newLogoValue)
    } else {
    }
  }, [cloudinaryStorageId]);

  return {
    cloudinaryStorageId,
    setCloudinaryStorageId,
    logoValue,
    setLogoValue
  };
};

export default useCloudinaryStorageId;
```

In addition, here are some functions that I used for fetching API

```
 const updateOrganizationBrandLogo = async (blob: Blob, onProgressChange: (progress: number) => void) => {
    if (applyBrandSettings) {
      const { status, storageId } = await imageService.uploadImage(blob, onProgressChange)
      if (status === 'success' && !!storageId) {
        await updateOrganizationLogoImageStorageId(storageId)
        setCloudinaryStorageId(storageId)
        //history.go(0);
      }
    }
  }


  const removeOrganizationLogoImage = () => {
    if (currentWorkspace?.id && applyBrandSettings) {
      updateOrganizationLogoImageStorageId('')
      setCloudinaryStorageId("")
      //history.go(0);
    }
  }
```